# updating sliderinput default value based on its output

Tags: r, shiny

I can't figure out how to this in shiny:
I have several variables (a, b, c) that user can select between them (lets say using selectinput). I have one sliderinput that determines the weights of this variables. So, if variable "a" is selected the sliderinput value will be assigned to this variable as weight. No problem so far. The problem rises when I change my selected variable (lets say to variable "b") and I want to update the initial value the sliderinput shows to be the weight of variable "b" (and not the last weight which is variable "a"). I tried many ways couldn't get my head around it. The code in the bottom generate a looping event.

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  selectInput("SelectIndicator", "Select Indicator", choices = c("a", "b", "c"),

  sliderInput('SelectIndicatorWeight', 'Select Indicator Weight',
              min=1, max=4, value= weight_holder[,1], # initial value
              step=1, round=0)
))

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
observe({
  indic_selected <- input$SelectIndicator
  x <- which(colnames(weight_holder) == indic_selected)
  updatesliderinput(session, "SelectIndicator", value = weight_holder[,x]
  weight_holder[,x] <- input$SelectIndicatorWeight
})
})
```

Comment: can you provide the weight_holder object? note you can use dput() or create a simple data.frame that will suit as a substitute.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reactiveVal` or `reactiveValues` to store the weights, and use `observeEvents` to listen to changes in one of your inputs. Here is a working example, hope this helps!

---

[image]

---

```
library(shiny)

# Values
my_object = c('a'=1,'b'=2,'c'=3)

ui <- fluidPage(

  selectInput("SelectIndicator", "Select Indicator", choices = c("a", "b", "c")),

  sliderInput('SelectIndicatorWeight', 'Select Indicator Weight',
              min=1, max=4, value= 1, # initial value
              step=1, round=0),

  tableOutput('mytable')
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # initialize the weights
  my_weights = reactiveValues(a=1,b=1,c=1)

  # If selected element changes, then update the slider
  observeEvent(input$SelectIndicator, {
    selected_weight = my_weights[[input$SelectIndicator]]
    updateSliderInput(session, "SelectIndicatorWeight", value = selected_weight)
  })

  # If slider changes, update the weights reactiveValues  
  observeEvent(input$SelectIndicatorWeight,
               {
                 my_weights[[input$SelectIndicator]] <- input$SelectIndicatorWeight
               })

  # Output the table
  output$mytable <- renderTable({
    weights = sapply(names(my_object),function(x) {my_weights[[x]]}) # get weights
    cbind(data.frame(my_object), weights) # create dataframe
  })

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```